# Category of integer vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

The objects of this category are all the possible vector columns $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{N}^n$. The morphisms are corresponding matrices with nonnegative integer entries, e.g. ${\bf E}$ is a morphism between ${\bf n}$ and ${\bf m}$ iff ${\bf m}={\bf E}{\bf n}$. One additional requirement: the matrices should not have zero rows and zero columns! For example,
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{{\bf E}}\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 5 \\ 4\end{pmatrix},\ \ where \ \ {\bf E}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Are there some books/articles, where this category (and, maybe, direct limits extensions in this category) considered?

Comment: Is $0\in\Bbb N$? Because if so, then this is not a category.

Comment: No, $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: In case it helps, this category is the category of elements of the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Mat}\to\mathbf{Set}$ (where $\mathbf{Mat}$ is the category whose objects are natural numbers and arrows $n\to m$ are matrices $m\times n$).

Comment: Alternatively, you can identify $\mathbf{Mat}$ with the full subcategory of the category of (commutative) monoids whose objects are the $\mathbb{N}^n$ (this way the functor is really "forgetful").

Comment: Yes, it is interesting. I am looking for some links with the number theory, some analogy with the category of natural numbers with division-morphisms, which is a sub-category here.